# Show text instead of date when no date is available

Tags: c#

In my program the date is written in a column from a Property path. However some of my data doesn't have a date so it just shows: 01-01-0001.

Ideally I would like it not to show anything or print Not Applicable when a date isn't available. Any help is appreciated.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Something" Width="120" Binding="{BindingSomethingData, StringFormat={}\{0:dd-MM-yyyy \}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: You can read about wpf converters.

Comment: @DmitriyKovalenko I'll do that right now.

Comment: you can read alos about the fallback property of the binding  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx